# If $\overline{B}(a_m,r_m)\subset \overline{B}(a_n,r_n)$ then show that $d(a_m,a_n)\leq r_n-r_m.$

Tags: general-topology, inequality, metric-spaces

If $\overline{B}(a_m,r_m)\subset \overline{B}(a_n,r_n)$ then show that $d(a_m,a_n)\leq r_n-r_m.$ Here assume that we are working in metric space $(X,d)$ and $\overline{B}(x,r)$ is simply the closed ball.

I can understand why this is true geometrically, but I do not know how to give a rigorous argument. Any hints will be much appreciated.

Comment: Does $\subset$ stand for strict inclusion?

Comment: @KaboMurphy No. It does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false. Consider the discrete metric, say on $\mathbb R$. Then the hypothesis holds whenever $r_m >1$ and $r_n >1$. Clearly the conclusion fails when $r_n-r_m <0$.

Comment: I see. I was afraid of this because I know that for normed spaces one can show this inequality, but I was not sure if the same holds for metric spaces. Thank you for your answer!